# Balance 2-wheels robot without making it drift forward/backward

Tags: control, wheeled-robot, matlab, c, balance

I'm trying to design a controller to balance a 2-wheels robot (around 13kg) and making it robust against external forces (e.g. if someone kicks it, it should not fall and not drift indefinitely forward/backward). I'm pretty experienced with most control techniques (LQR, Sliding Mode Control, PID etc), but I've seen online that most people use LQR for balancing 2-wheels robots, hence I'm going with LQR.
My problem is that, despite I'm able to make the robot not fall down, it rapidly starts going forward/backward indefinitely, and I don't how to make it mantain a certain position on the ground. What I want to achieve is that, when the robot gets kicked by an external force, it must be able to stop moving forward/backward while mantaining the balance (it's not necessary to mantain a position on the ground, I just want the robot to stop moving).
The measurements to which I have access from the sensors are: position on both wheels (x), velocity of both wheels (x_dot), angular position of robot (theta), angular velocity of robot (theta_dot).
Since now I tried 2 approaches:

1. set all reference signals to 0 and try to tune the LQR gain. With this (simple) approach I'm not sure if the coefficients of gain K relative to x and theta should have same or opposite sign, because, if for example the robot gets kicked away from its reference for x, the wheels should move in the direction that makes the robot return to the 0 point, but this would make theta go in the opposite direction. When the robot gets kicked, I would like that first theta gets adjusted in order to brake the movement given by the external force, and then x_dot should go in the same direction as theta in order to stop the robot.
2. use best LQR gains that I could find empirically/with MATLAB and use some "heuristic" in order to, given the current state of the robot (x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot), choose the reference signals for the state variables. I tried the heuristic "if x_dot goes forward/backward, then make theta inclide backward/forward", which makes the robot avoid drifting forward/backward in case there're no disturbances, but if I kick the robot it starts oscillating really fast until it falls (I tried to adjust the K gain of LQR to solve this problem, but I couldn't find any that solved it).

Which approach would you suggest me to use? Should I implement some more sophisticated heuristics (any suggestion?) or should I just tune the LQR gain until I find the perfect one? Should I consider using an integrator (for controlling which states?) together with the LQR?

Any advice would be highly appreciated. I'm kind of desperate.

Comment: https://youtu.be/fusr9eTceEo

Comment: After a disturbance, besides seeking to remain vertical, does the control algorithm also seek to end up at zero speed?